# How to include the Login.php in my custom template? — Magento 2.2

Tags: php, blocks, template, magento2.2, paths

I am new to Magento, I am not yet familiar with how the paths are working.
I am trying to override file Login.php the in the following path:

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Form/Login.php
```

I am trying to have a new copy in my custom template:`app/design/frontend/Mine/CustomTemplate` but I cannot find how to find the path in which I need to place the duplicated file, in order to override it. 
Anybody has an idea about where the right path should be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use theme fallback to override php class. Just [create your module](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/) 
 And [override standard php block](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/) with your own or use plugin feature. If need some help with this also, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dependency injection and extend original Login.php block or use a plugin (if it fits your function needs). Google it like "How to extend block for the Magento 2". You will find a lot of good examples.

You can't put .php file into one of the directories and expect it to work, that is not possible on the Magento 2 (There was a way on magento 1 by using codePools).